# understanding the google glog macro

Tags: android, c++, glog

When I read the source code of google glog, I found the following macro confusing to me:

```
#define LOG_IF(severity, condition) \
    static_cast<void>(0),             \
    !(condition) ? (void) 0 : google::LogMessageVoidify() & LOG(severity)
```

1. What's the meaning of `static_cast<void>(0),`?
2. What's the meaning of `&` in the third line?
3. What does the result look like if we expand this macro?

I'm new to c++. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: it's three different questions, I provide an alternative title

Comment: These are basic constructs of the language that are better learnt from [a good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of SO.